# Coavarianc matrix determinant and inverse

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, covariance

Let $C$ be a positive semi-definite symmetric covariance matrix;  $I$ be an identity matrix;   $\sigma^{2}$ a constant

How can I find the determinant and inverse of 
$$|C+\sigma^{2}I|$$ and $$(C+\sigma^{2}I)^{-1}$$

I am mostly interested in a method to separate $C$ from  $\sigma^{2}$ or simplify the calculations

Answer (score 1):

You must compute the matrix $D = C + \sigma^2 I$ first and then compute the inverse or determinant of $D$. It cannot be done faster for a general symmetric positive semi-definite matrices $C$.